# Select from table using '_id' in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause, android-cursor

I want to select a specific row from my sqlite database using the id as selection.
In my database the id is called _id. I want to use the following function and the parameter is the id of the row which I want to select and save into a cursor.
DATABASE_TABLE_Bewirtschafter is the name of my table.

```
public Cursor createBewirtschafterIDCursor(int id) {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_Bewirtschafter, null, "_id = " + id,
                null, null, null, null);
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and I get a null pointer exception.
This works:

```
public Cursor createBewirtschafterListViewCursor(String like) {
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_Bewirtschafter, null, "gewName LIKE '%" + like + "%'",
            null, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it helped you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes because you are passing null in column parameter in you query

```
db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_Bewirtschafter, null, "_id = " + id,
                null, null, null, null);
```

Whereas you should pass a String array there name of different colums.. for ref please check

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: Thanks. In my edit you can see my other statement which works fine and the columns are also null. Why?

Comment: Found my failure. I forgot to open the database.

Answer (score 1):

What's your `db` variable set to? Judging from the code you've shown, that's pretty much what I'd guess causes the `NullPointerException` to be thrown.

Comment: db = context.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);